# jQuery, how to pass an rgb value to change a css background?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, colors, background-color

I can change the css background color with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").css("background-color", "blue");
});
```

but I want to pass an RGB color, I tried changing

```
"blue"
```

with

```
"rbg(102, 250, 60)"
```

and without the doublequote, nothing works

Comment: Do you mean that only the `rgb()` doesn't work? Or that neither value works without the double quotes?

Comment: Note you misspelled: `rgb`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have a typo?

I see "rbg(...)" instead of "rgb(...)" in your question

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this, reference: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/adding-rgb-value-to-background-color

```
$("body").css({'background-color': "rgb(102, 250, 60)" });
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you write `rgb`. change your code like the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").css("background-color", "rgb(102, 250, 60)");
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Why can't you do it with doublequotes?

You can use this function to convert RGB to hex:

```
function rgb2hex(rgb){
    rgb = rgb.match(/^rgb((d+),s*(d+),s*(d+))$/);
    return "#" +
        ("0" + parseInt(rgb[1],10).toString(16)).slice(-2) +
        ("0" + parseInt(rgb[2],10).toString(16)).slice(-2) +
        ("0" + parseInt(rgb[3],10).toString(16)).slice(-2);
}
```